# why does "ig" repeat twice?

Tags: java, arrays

I was given to code something similar to piglatin. But I am getting the "ig" of pig in latin. What is wrong with the code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = s.nextLine();
        String end = "ay";
        int i, j;
        String word = "";
        String[] arr = str.split(" ");
        for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            String indWord = arr[j];
            char c = indWord.charAt(0);
            for (i = 1; i < indWord.length(); i++) {
                word = word + indWord.charAt(i);
            }
            String res = "";
            res = word + c + end + " ";
            System.out.print(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Axpected:

```
pig latin ----> igpay atinlay
```

Actual:

[image: this is what I am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not clearing the `word` variable for each iteration... that was hard to see because your indentation is wrong.

Move the `String word="";` line to the inside of the `for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++){` loop so that the `word` variable is cleared for every word and you start over (instead of carrying its contents from the last word)